# Starting to iterate from a position in an itertools.product object

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm using the python itertools module to create a generator that iterates from `aaa` to `ccc`.

I cant figure out a way to start the iteration from a certain position
for example if the input is `aba` the iteration will continue from that position
this is how my code looks like now:

```
from itertools import product

strings = itertools.product(*["abc"]*3)
for item in strings:
    print("".join(item))
```

Comment: Can you include the expected input and output of your program?

Comment: I edited to post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method doesn't skip any of the computation, it just drops values until it sees the one it's looking for. This should work on any iterable, but there may be a `product` specific solution that would allow you to skip generating the values you don't care about.

```
from itertools import dropwhile, product

def resume(iterable, sentinel):
    yield from dropwhile(lambda x: x != sentinel, iterable)

for t in resume(product('abc', repeat=3), ('a', 'b', 'a')):
    print(*t)
```